# Remove duplicates from list type pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1        col2
[1,2,3]     [4,5]
[1,2,3]     [6,7]
[4,5,6]     [8,9]
[9,8,7,1]   [1,2]
[9,8,7,1]   [3,4]
```

Now I want to remove duplicates from col1, and keep the first row of duplicate values so the data frame would look like,

```
col1        col2
[1,2,3]     [4,5]
[4,5,6]     [8,9]
[9,8,7,1]   [1,2]
```

As .drop_duplicates() not working here looking for some pandas solutions to do this more efficiently other than using a for loop.

Comment: Please explain why rdop_duplicates doesn't do it ?

Comment: It doe's work with list type columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try mapping the lists in `col1` to `tuple`, then we can use `duplicated` to create a boolean mask which can be used to filter the rows

```
df[~df['col1'].map(tuple).duplicated()]
```

---

```
           col1   col2
0     [1, 2, 3]  [4,5]
2     [4, 5, 6]  [8,9]
3  [9, 8, 7, 1]  [1,2]
```

PS: For `drop_duplicates` to work the values in the column must be `hashable` or in other words `immutable`.